# ImageView manipulation in Java

Tags: android

I have an ImageView created in my xml layout. I then access the ImageView in my Java with the following:

```
ImageView iv1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv1);
```

I'm then accessing the ImageView's OnClick method. When the ImageView is clicked I would like to change it's position on the screen. In the XML side I can do this with layout_margin, but I can't figure out how that is done in the Java side.

Could anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set margins programmatically using LayoutParams, please try with following code:

LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
     LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

layoutParams.setMargins(30, 20, 30, 0);

and set this layout param object to your view by using:

view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

Answer (score 0):

i think you should change layout parameters by setLayoutParamerter method of View class  see [Discription](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setLayoutParams%28android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams%29).

this is not the big task, even you can add this view at any particular place by using Relative layout.